# IdentityServer4 high availability?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

Is there a recommended way how to configure an IdentityServer for high availability? What are pros/cons for one solution over the other.
Currently I use ARR for it, but I've some issues and I'm not sure if it is the best solution anyhow?

Comment: Your question quite wide and not sure about what you intend to do. Please explain your production deployment environment for ensuring you understand well about high availability because it depends on the environment first and code following later.

Comment: I've an IdentityServer currently running on one server in the datacenter and I need to make sure that I can authenticate even if one server goes down; similar to a web farm.
So the question is mainly about on which layer should/can I setup up the load balancer and are there any IdentityServer specific things I need to be aware off?

Comment: So in that case I highly recommend you should look at using stateless token for scaling multiple authenticated servers such as applying Jwt token and a proxy such as Nginx, HA Proxy to load balancing between them. There is no correct answer for your question because it depends on the individual environment.

Comment: Or you can look at the Cloud solution to turn on High availability for it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a question specific to ASP.Net Core or IDS4 and to do it to a degree where it really is truly HA is quite hard.

That said, if not talking about Amazon/Azure stuff... I'd do something like this:

Two sets of servers, each in geographically separate sites, combined with a multi-site SQL Server AlwaysOn High Availability Group using synchronous commits and automatic fail-over and the app configured to suit (i.e. MultiSubnetFailover=true).

In front of the each set of web servers have a traffic manager (with its own HA) with health checking enabled and then in front of that have active DNS failover via a service like Dyn (https://dyn.com/active-failover/)

This would allow you to suffer an entire data centre going down or any individual server and carry on like nothing happened.